# TeamCity: wrong messages order in Build Log when writing to stderr and stdout

Tags: teamcity, stdout, stderr

Simple python script:

```
for i in range(0, 5):
  print "ok"
  sys.stderr.write('err\r\n')
```

When executing this script under TeamCity (build step), following output appears in Build Log tab:

```
ok
err
ok
ok
ok
err
ok
err
err
err
```

Messages go in wrong completely random order.

Please suggest how to make messages go in same order they are written to output.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a [known issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/TW-14648), please star/vote.

Comment: Thanks, voted. Do you know some "workarounds" until this problem hasn't been fixed?

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to write to stdout and stderr to distinguish between messages and errors, you could try to use service messages: http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD65/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity. They are using only one channel to distinguish different messages and do not go in wrong order.

Comment: Yes, it's a good suggestion to use TeamCity specific messages.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use TeamCity messages because I don't want rewrite my Python scripts and replace messages to stderr with TeamCity messages (some scripts are third-party)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a partial workaround for bash scripts:

```
sync() {
  (
    { set +x; } 2> /dev/null # silently disable xtrace
    sleep 0.1 # synchronize stdout and stderr for TeamCity
    "${'$'}@"
    local exit_code=${'$'}?
    sleep 0.1 # synchronize stdout and stderr for TeamCity
    return ${'$'}exit_code
  )
}
```

Now you can synchronize `stdout` and `stderr` at least before and after important commands:

```
set -x
sync wget http://examples.com/
sync bash myscript.sh arg1 arg2
```

Before this change TeamCity could show printed bash command after some lines printed by this command.